# Check for number of files starting with some string

Tags: java, android

I want to check in my SD card root for files starting with "thisfile" and return the number of files in an int or a string.

For example i have 10 files on my SD card with the following names:

```
thisfile1.txt
thisfile444.txt
thisfileffvdfv.txt
thisfilefdfvdfv.txt
thisfile4fvdfv.txt
thisfilefvdfvdf.txt
thisfiledfvdfvdfv.txt
thisfilefdvdfvdf.txt
thisfilewedwed.txt
thisfilewedwedfff.txt
```

For this example, I want my code to return 10 for this.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    int num=0;
    String[] children = dir.list();
    if (children == null) {
        // Either dir does not exist or is not a directory
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            // Get filename of file or directory
            String filename = children[i];
          if(filename.startsWith("thisfile")
              num++;
        }
    }

System.out.println("total number "+num);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int numberOfFiles=0;
  File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  String[] children = dir.list();
  for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
       if (children[i].startsWith("file")
        numberOfFiles++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do : `directory.list()` to get the filenames of your current directory.
You go through your array of files, and check if the filename contains "thisfile" by using

```
String.contains(CharSequence cs)
```

Each time the **contains** method returns true, you increment a variable, which will be the number of times you have found the sequence "thisfile" in the name of files in your directory

Comment: This is close, but it might return false positives-- if `cs` is in the `String` object but not at the beginning, it will still return true.

Comment: Yes, I read too fast, haven't noticed it was necessary that the substring has to be at the beginning of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fileNameFilter to filter out the files first :

```
class MyFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

            return (name.startsWith("thisfile"));

    }
```

Inside your Activity use:

```
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
int counter =home.listFiles(new MyFilter()).length
```